# Get AST of a file inside other file

Tags: javascript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm creating a custom eslint rule, to check that for each graph, all the dependencies are defined. So I'm going over the files AST, but sometimes a graph has subgraphs, so I need to go over the subgraphs AST too.
How can I do so?

I have tried to import fs and path libraries to open the other file I need but the import state shows an error.

```js
const TSESTree = require('@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree');
const { ESLint } = require('eslint');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  'defined-dependencies': {
    meta: {
      docs: {
        description:
          'The dependency must be defined',
        recommended: 'error',
      },
      messages: {
        dependencyUndefined: 'One of the dependencies is undefined {{ dependencyName }}',
      },
      schema: [],
      hasSuggestions: false,
      type: 'suggestion',
    },
    defaultOptions: [],
    create(
      context,
    ) {
      return {
        ClassDeclaration(node) {
          const decorators = node.decorators;
          if (decorators) {
            const decoratorNames = decorators.map(decorator => getDecoratorName(decorator));
            if (decoratorNames.includes('Graph')) {
              const subGraphs = getSubGraphs(decorators);
              if (subGraphs.length > 0) {
                findFileByName(subGraphs[0]);
              }

              if (true){
                context.report({
                  node: node,
                  messageId: 'dependencyUndefined',
                  data: {
                    dependencyName: findFileByName(subGraphs[0]),
                  },
                });
              }
            }

          }
        },
      };
    },
  },
};
function getSubGraphs(node ) {
  const args= node?.expression?.arguments;
  if (args) {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      if (args[i].type == TSESTree.AST_NODE_TYPES.ObjectExpression) {
        const properties = args[i].properties;
        if (properties) {
          for (let j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
            if (properties[j].key.name == 'subGraphs') {
              return properties[j].value.elements.map(subGraph => subGraph.name);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return [];
}

function findFileByName(name) {
  const searchDirectory = './'; // Directory to start the search from
  const files = fs.readdirSync(searchDirectory);

  for (const file of files) {
    const filePath = path.join(searchDirectory, file);
    const stats = fs.statSync(filePath);

    if (stats.isFile() && file === `${name}.ts`) {
      return filePath;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

function getDecoratorName(decorator) {
  return ((decorator?.expression)?.callee)?.name;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.